# How to remember and easily switch between monitor configurations in KDE?

Tags: kde, xrandr, monitors

I've got two monitors and I'm using KDE. I use following monitor configurations:

- two monitors (one little bit lower than another one) for usual work
- the beautiful IPS monitor for movies
- the fast TN monitor for gaming

I don't like to always have to go to display settings, and configure layout manually for each change. Is there any KDE way to store and switch between monitor profiles/configurations?

Disclaimer: I know that I can create shell scripts to switch layouts using xrandr. But, isn't there any GUI way to do this in KDE?

Comment: I'm looking for a tool like this as well, but nothing for 3 years + 3 months :-( On Windows I use this amazing tool https://sourceforge.net/projects/monitorswitcher/ and I can't find anything like it on Linux... shame Linux isn't supported because of fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. disable kscreen
2. create appropriate xrandr scripts using arandr
3. create desktop or toolbar links to the scripts